# repeat local notification not working in react-native-push-notification

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I am using react-native-push-notification for showing local-notifications in my react-native app. I want to repeat notification every week at 10 a.m. I wrote following code:

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import PushController from './Components/PushController';


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.notify.bind(this);
  }

  notify = () => {
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
       message: 'You pushed a notification',
       repeatType: 'week',
       date: // what should I write here ...??? 
    });
  }

}
```

How do I show notification every week. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use moment.js to get the dates accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass your selected date in moment look like

```
 notify = () => {
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        message: 'You pushed a notification',
        repeatType: 'week',
        date: new Date(selected date and time)//Thu Feb 27 2020 18:22:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
   });
}
```